# Why does my project still run when throw UnsupportedUserException?

Tags: php, symfony4

Provider:

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class SSOProvider implements UserProviderInterface{
  private $entityManager;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager){
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  }

  public function loadUserByUsername($username){
    return $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:User')->findOneByUsername($username);
  }

  public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user){
    if (!$user instanceof User)
      throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
    return $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:User')->findOneByUsername($user->getUsername());
  }

   public function supportsClass($class){
      return User::class === $class;
   }
}
```

I followed [this guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html), and I wanna know how UnsupportedUserException works, so I try to modify refreshUser() as below:

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user){
    throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
    return $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:User')->findOneByUsername($user->getUsername());
  }
```

My project still runs to the line

```
throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class "%s".', get_class($user)));
```

But it didn't throw an exception. Please tell me why my project still runs, thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? We all want to help you ;)

Comment: What happens if you put an echo at the end of your function (to https://hastebin.com/cabumutexu.php)?

Comment: it won't run (echo "oh no";). it stops at UnsupportedUserException.

Comment: I think it throws an exception, because it stops executing. Are error messages suppressed?

Comment: If I use \Exception instead of UnsupportedUserException. \Exception will throw an exception with a message error and UnsupportedUserException won't. Idk why UnsupportedUserException just stops the function and not throw an exception.

Comment: Maybe somewhere is a set_exception_handler or a try-catch block that handles UnsupportedUserException, but re-throws \Exception.